# Getting the event logs using Get-EventLogs in powershell as another user

Tags: powershell

i want to get the event logs as a different user via powershell. I have looked up almost all the online resources but was unable to find a way to get event logs a another user via powershell.

Comment: Either use `Invoke-Command` or give your current user permission to read the logs.

Answer (score 0):

Get-EventLogs does not support using alternative credentials, but `Get-WinEvent` does.

```
$credential = Get-Credential
Get-WinEvent -Credential $credential
```